# Validating date format

Tags: vba, excel

Anybody knows how to validate date format in the format of `mm/dd/yyyy`.
I have tried this code but is not working.

In the userform:

```
dateCheck (txtStartDate)
```

In module:

```
Function dateCheck(dateValue As Date) As Boolean
    If CDate(dateValue) <> "mm/dd/yyyy" Then
        MsgBox "Please use the mm/dd/yyyy  date format!"
        dateCheck = True
    End If
End Function
```

Am I on the right track? Thanks!

Comment: Are you aware of the [VBA function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg278584%28v=office.15%29.aspx) `IsDate`?

Comment: Yes, Im aware of it.

Comment: a user may input 05/01/2016 which he/she meant 5-Jan-2016 but your userform will interpret as 1-May-2016. Avoid all the anomaly, let user input in any format they like but always change entered date into 'dd-mmm-yyyy` format. Excel can recognize the localized format and change them to your preferred format accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

```
Function dateCheck(dateStrng As String) As Boolean
Dim dateArr as Variant 

If IsDate(dateStrng) Then ' <~~ if it IS a date
   dateArr = Split(dateStrng,"/")
   If UBound(dateArr) = 2 Then '<~~ if it has three substrings separate by two "slashes"
      If CInt(dateArr(0)) < 13 Then  '<~~ if the 1st number is lower or equals the maximum possible month number
         If CInt(dateArr(0)) > 0 Then  '<~~ if the 1st number is higher or equals the mimimum possible month number
            If CInt(dateArr(1)) < 31 Then  '<~~ if the 2nd number is lower or equals the maximum possible day number
               If CInt(dateArr(1)) > 0 Then  '<~~ if the 2nd number is higher or equals the mimimum possible day number
                  If CInt(dateArr(2)) < 10000 Then dateCheck = CInt(dateArr(2)) > 999  '<~~ if the 3rd number is a 4 digit integer "year" number, then check returns True
               End If
            End If
         End If
      End If
   End If
End Function
```

Comment: @kruk22: did you try this?

Comment: @kruk22: it'd be nice from you to give feedback on attempts at helping you

Comment: This certainly is the closest answer. The only issue I have with it is that a valid mm/dd/yyyy date should be able to contain a 3-digit year, you should check length of the year parameter instead. E.g. in your function, 12/1/0900 is invalid, and 12/1.5/002002.8 is valid.

Comment: @user3598756 Added another if condition to set the start year  to 1950 when working on my code.

Answer (score 1):

The `CDate(dateValue)` part of your function will simply return 'dateValue' as a `Date`. Use the `.Numberformat` property to get the format:

```
Function dateCheck(dateValue As Date) As Boolean
    If dateValue.NumberFormat <> "mm/dd/yyyy" Then
        MsgBox "Please use the mm/dd/yyyy  date format!"
        dateCheck = True
    End If
End Function
```

Comment: The OP mentioned the use of a form. Are you sure that `.NumberFormat` is available on which ever control the OP is using in his/her form?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that your question is compounded. There are actually two steps involved to your question:

1. Is `txtStartDate` actually a valid date?
2. If it is a date, is it formatted correctly?

The naming of `txtStartDate` implies that you are getting a date as a text (in a form). Yet, you are passing it to your function with the assumption that `txtStartDate` is actually a date. This becomes obvious because the function `dateCheck` expects a date: `Function dateCheck(dateValue As Date) As Boolean`.

So, here is a solution proposal to solve both at once:

```
Sub tmpTest()

Dim txtStartDate As String

txtStartDate = "11/20/2015"

Debug.Print dateCheck(txtStartDate)

End Sub
```

---

```
Function dateCheck(dateValue As String) As Boolean

If IIf(IsDate(txtStartDate), Format(CDate(txtStartDate), "mm/dd/yyyy"), "") = dateValue Then dateCheck = True

End Function
```

Keep in mind that this is a very simplistic approach which will not work for international date formats. In fact, you might have to adjust it a bit as I do not have your date format. If you need something more sophisticated then you will have to write a bit more VBA code (including an extensive validation function).

Comment: Yes, this works if the user inputs a valid date. But if not, it returns error. Can we just try to use On error Resume Next Statement to handle the error? But I don't know how to imply it. It's just my idea.

Comment: The function should always return `True` or `False` and not an error. At least this is what I get here. Yet, I am aware that the above is a very simplistic (as mentioned before) approach and does not cover many cases. Creating a sophisticated date-validation function including many different international date formats and other conveniences (such as the following dates `05/19` auto-completes to `05/19/2016` and `-7` will automatically revert to the date one week ago) will require a lot more VBA coding.

Comment: To make it a bit more internationally compatible you can use `"mm\/dd\/yyyy"` instead of `"mm/dd/yyyy"` as argument for `Format`. It then forces the `/`s. On my system `Format` replaces `/` with `.` if I use `"mm/dd/yyyy"`(which is a bad thing to do imo).

Answer (score 0):

Can just use IsDate() to validate the date format.